# Restore cell value on a certain condtion

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to restore the default value of a cell when a field in `DB` gets/will get updated to a certain value?

Pseudo Code:

```
Update mytable Set Status equal to Default 
   if QCField to be updated has
      value='A' or 'B' and and also update QCField to 'A'
```

Here `Status`,`QCField` are fields in the table.

Edit:Default value is not `null` but is some text.

Comment: The default value you mean the one of the table definition?

Comment: Is the column nullable? If so, do you want NULL back? Or could you just tell us the default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the last time I'll edit this answer because you keep changing the question. From the comment on the other answer:

> I want to update Status only when QCField has value either A or B, but
>   not matter what, QCField has to get updated – Suhail Gupta

You either have to do two update statements:

- one which updates `QCField` to A, and the status value to "some text" where `QCField` is A or B
- one which updates the `QCField` to A where `QCField` is not currently A or B

---

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    Status = 'Some text',
       QCField = 'A'
WHERE  QCField IN ('A', 'B');

UPDATE mytable
SET    QCField = 'A'
WHERE  QCField NOT IN ('A', 'B');
```

---

Alternatively, you can do one update statement which touches every row:

- Updating `QCField` to A
- If the `QCField` is A or B update the status to "some text", otherwise leave it at the current value.

---

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    Status = CASE
                  WHEN QCField IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'Some text'
                  ELSE Status
                END,
       QCField = 'A';
```

Comment: I could not quite understand `WHERE  QCField IN ('A', 'B')` What will happen if `QCField = 'Z'`?

Comment: Nothing - it only updates rows where the value in the QCField column is one of the values specified

Comment: @SuhailGupta I have updated my answer one last time to reflect the new information you have given us.